# Getting Background Color of textView (I have no idea whats going on)

Tags: android

So i have this code and i'm trying to get current background color of the textView that has been clicked on.

I get the following error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable

```
private final class ChoiceTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            TextView textViewTouched = (TextView) view;

***error at this line***  ColorDrawable textViewBackground = (ColorDrawable)textViewTouched.getBackground();


            //change color of textView quickly so that the shadow dragged object made down below
            //will have a different colour then textView
            view.setBackgroundColor(0xfff00000);

            //setup drag
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
            //start dragging the item touched
            view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);

            //change the textView colour back so the user doesn't see a change so that the
            //shadow object is a different colour then the textView
            view.setBackgroundColor(0xf32cd320); 
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

But if I move

```
ColorDrawable textViewBackground = (ColorDrawable)textViewTouched.getBackground();
```

To below

```
view.setBackgroundColor(0xfff00000);
```

It works just fine.

I have no idea why its doing what its doing but I need to get the background color before I apply the new color.

***edit***

I should also mention i have this in a function lower down in my code and it works just fine in that function.

***More Edit***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/DisplayConfig"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="18.5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:text="@string/intro" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/option_1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/drag_drop_option"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="@string/option_1"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_height="150dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/option_2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/drag_drop_option"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="@string/option_2"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:layout_height="150dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/option_3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/drag_drop_option"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="@string/option_3"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:layout_height="151dp" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/bottom_button_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button android:id="@+id/occupancy_button"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Room Mode"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

and setting of the view for the listener is done like this.

```
option1.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
```

Comment: if `option1` is inflated from XML id `android:id="@+id/option_1"` then it have `Drawable` resource `drag_drop_option`, not a solid color... you said in prev comment that you have `android:background="#32cd32" ` set but i don't see this line here anywhere. especially for `TextViews`

Comment: sorry that was something i was trying. it was android:background="#32cd32" at the time of the error and now it just points to <solid android:color="#32cd32" />

Comment: I don't think it was... show code, which throws you exception, excagly code. this with line `android:background="@drawable/drag_drop_option"` you may get one, with `"#32cd32"` I don't think so...

Comment: all thats in that drag_drop_option is <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:dither="true" >

    <solid android:color="#32cd32" />

    <corners android:radius="2dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#32cd32" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="5dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="5dp" />

</shape>

Comment: `ColorDrawable` don't have corners. [GradientDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html) have

Comment: I don't know what happened before... but you are correct now. if i take out that file and all references it works. Thanks!

Comment: please consider upvote and answer accept if helpful :) Good luck!

Comment: I am still under 15 reputation so when i click upvote it just says it wont change the publicly displayed post score. But thank you so much for all your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you don't have `ColorDrawable` but another type, so you are getting `ClassCast`?

Look [HERE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html), `Drawable` have a lot of subclasses

> **Known Direct Subclasses**
>
> AnimatedVectorDrawable, AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat, BitmapDrawable, **ColorDrawable**, DrawableContainer, DrawableWrapper, DrawerArrowDrawable, **GradientDrawable**, LayerDrawable, NinePatchDrawable, PictureDrawable, RoundedBitmapDrawable, ShapeDrawable, VectorDrawable, VectorDrawableCompat
>
> **Known Indirect Subclasses**
>
> AnimatedStateListDrawable, AnimationDrawable, ClipDrawable, InsetDrawable, LevelListDrawable, PaintDrawable, RippleDrawable, RotateDrawable, ScaleDrawable, StateListDrawable, TransitionDrawable

edit:

[getBackground() method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getBackground()) returns `Drawable` and you are immediatelly casting this to `(ColorDrawable)`. stacktrace says that this is not `ColorDrawable, but GradientDrawable`, another subclass of `Drawable`

[setBackgroundColor(int color)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor(int)) is creating `ColorDrawable` for background, so when you move below your line with casting to `ColorDrawable` then is working

it may don't throw any errors for other views, because these might have set background color earlier in another way

edit2:

you may check with `instanceOf`, but this is not an efficient and optimal way to resolve your problem...

```
if( ! textViewTouched.getBackground() instanceOf ColorDrawable)
    textViewTouched.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#32cd32"));
ColorDrawable textViewBackground = (ColorDrawable)textViewTouched.getBackground();
```

Comment: have **import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;**  but also tried **import android.graphics.drawable.*;**

Comment: imports are automatic and doesn't matter here at all... see edit

Comment: is there another way i can create a ColorDrawable with out setting the color?

Comment: if you don't want a color maybe use transparent? e.g. `Color.TRANSPARENT` [there is a constructor with **int color**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ColorDrawable.html) for programmatic way and you may set it "earlier" in XML layout file (if present)

Comment: sorry... i'm still pretty new to all this. I want the current color from the background. it does have one. i just need to store what it is before i change it. so i don't really know how it doesn't have a ColorDrawable for the background when the background has color currently (android:background is set in the xml file)

Comment: android:background="#32cd32"

Comment: are you sure that there is not `style` line overriding your line or other place in code when may be some theme or style set differently?

Comment: i do apply a theme in the manifest the parent of which is android:Theme.Holo.Light

Comment: nope, `android:background` overrides `Theme` set by manifest, I'm asking about Java code. you clearly setting gradient for background in some point after inflating XML. I doubt that `android:background="#32cd32"` is setting `GradientDrawable` instead of `ColorDrawable`. show initiation of `View` to which you want to attach your `OnTouchListener`. and whole XML